# Why is the std::bitset<8> variable unable to handle 11111111?

Tags: c++, binary, bitset

Why is this program showing the following output ?

```
#include <bitset>
...

{
    std::bitset<8> b1(01100100); std::cout<<b1<<std::endl;
    std::bitset<8> b2(11111111); std::cout<<b2<<std::endl; //see, this variable
                                                           //has been assigned
                                                           //the value 11111111
                                                           //whereas, during
                                                           //execution, it takes
                                                           //the value 11000111
    std::cout << "b1 & b2: " << (b1 & b2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "b1 | b2: " << (b1 | b2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "b1 ^ b2: " << (b1 ^ b2) << '\n';
}
```

This is the OUTPUT:

```
01000000
11000111
b1 & b2: 01000000
b1 | b2: 11000111
b1 ^ b2: 10000111
```

First, I thought there is something wrong with the header file (I was using MinGW) so I
checked using MSVCC. But it too showed the same thing. Please help.

Comment: using 0xff will fix it (or 0b11111111 is your compiler supports it)

Comment: It might be kinda neat if it did binary initialization in decimal like that

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Despite the appearance, the `11111111` is decimal. The binary representation of `11111111`<sub>10</sub> is `101010011000101011000111`<sub>2</sub>. Upon construction, `std::bitset<8>` takes the eight least significant bits of that: `11000111`<sub>2</sub>.

The first case is similar except the `01100100` is octal (due to the leading zero). The same number expressed in binary is `1001000000001000000`<sub>2</sub>.

One way to represent a bitset with a value of `11111111`<sub>2</sub> is `std::bitset<8> b1(0xff)`.

Alternatively, you can construct a bitset from a binary string:

```
std::bitset<8> b1(std::string("01100100"));
std::bitset<8> b2(std::string("11111111"));
```

Answer (score 7):

As per NPE's answer, you are constructing the `bitset` with an `unsigned long`, and not with bits as you were expecting. An alternative way to construct it, which enables you to specify the bits, is by using the `string` constructor as follows:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> b1(std::string("01100100")); std::cout<<b1<<std::endl;
    std::bitset<8> b2(std::string("11111111")); std::cout<<b2<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "b1 & b2: " << (b1 & b2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "b1 | b2: " << (b1 | b2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "b1 ^ b2: " << (b1 ^ b2) << '\n';
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

[Click here](http://ideone.com/2b7KXJ) to view the output.